# Android - Restrict EditText entry after centain VALUE (ex. $100)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I would like to restrict the EditText entry with a certain value (not maxlength).

Example - MaxValue is $100.

Possible maximum value inputs are
100, 100.0, 100.00

So I cannot restrict it with maxlength.

Is it possible to restrict when the user enters the value?

or checking the value `if(edittextvalue>100)` on **TextChangeListener** is the only option?

Comment: Checking in the TextWatcher is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to restrict when the user enters the value?

Yes,You should use [**`TextWatcher`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) . I hope this is best way .

> When an object of a type is attached to an Editable, its methods will
>   be called when the text is changed.

```
private final TextWatcher TxtWatecherExample= new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         // Add your LOGIC
           if()
           {}
           else
           {}
        }

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    };
```

[**`onTextChanged`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int))

> **void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, 
>                   int start, 
>                   int before, 
>                   int count)** This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced
>   old text that had length before. It is an error to attempt to make
>   changes to s from this callback.

Comment: Downvoting. This answer is not giving any solution to op. The op already knew about it from `TextChangeListener`.

Answer (score 0):

> add the `addTextChangedListener` event to your `editText`
>
> like this.

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                try {
                    double value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                    if (value >= 100.0) {
                        // Your code goes here.
                    } else {
                        // Your code goes here.
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Handle empty string. Since we're passing the edittext value.
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Hope this will help.